# ASP.NET WEb.config Referencing an assembly

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Hi I have 3 lines of code generated in my Web.config (.net 4.0) project as below

```
<configSections>
      <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

When I run the project I get the error
: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

However I am referencing that assembly Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data from a private folder where it may not have a strong name etc in the project(I do Add references,Browse to private folder and add the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
library).

I hope I can find the added library somewhere in project configuration(No idea where - I searched properties etc. So I can substitute that value without strong name etc in Web.config and get going. Can somebody give a hand ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open a new project and try adding the references via NuGet and compare your config entries.

You just have the wrong version of the assembly referenced.

Comment: In a web project how do you find the version of files referenced-There is nothing in web.config and nothing in project properties and I could not use ildasm

Answer (score 0):

I found there was a problem in my connect string . I was having a connection for SQL Server Compact and I did not have the providename. This was leading to problems.